# How can i get output like this in swift

Tags: swift, nsdictionary

**{ length = 30, contents = "something", count = 32.3 }**

I need exact output in this bracket {  } not in() or []

```
var array:Array<Any> = Array<Any>();
array.append(NSDictionary(object: singleItem.name, forKey: "name" as NSCopying));
array.append(NSDictionary(object: singleItem.planned_revenue, forKey: "planned_revenue" as NSCopying));
array.append(NSDictionary(object: singleItem.phone, forKey: "phone" as NSCopying));
array.append(NSDictionary(object: singleItem.description, forKey: "description" as NSCopying));
array.append(NSDictionary(object: singleItem.email_from, forKey: "email_from" as NSCopying));
 array.append(NSDictionary(object: singleItem.probability, forKey: "probability" as NSCopying));
```

output

```
[{
    name = "this is another";
}, {
    "planned_revenue" = "0.0";
}, {
    phone = "";
}, {
    description = "Internal Notes";
}, {
    "email_from" = "thomas.passot@agrolait.example.com";
}, {
    probability = "20.0";
}]
```

I need like

```
[{ name = "this is another", "planned_revenue" = "0.0", phone = "", description = "Internal Notes", ..... }]
```

Comment: this is `[AnyHashable:Any]`

Comment: `print("{ length = 30, contents = \"something\", count = 32.3 }")`. However I don't think thats what you want. You need to add more information on where this output is coming from.

Comment: `print("{ length = 30, contents = \"something\", count = 32.3 }")`

Comment: i want to do it in a dictionary. @Anbu.Karthik why -1 ? instead of help ?

Comment: can you show ur tried code

Comment: We've spent more time helping than you elaborating your question. If you want more help, try adding more details and narrowing your question.

Comment: Hi @Anbu.Karthik I edited the question, can you please help ? i don't know how to use [AnyHashable : Any] please . ..

Comment: @PRINCE - your quetion is good

Comment: Try using a single dictionary instead of an array of dictionaries.

Comment: Can you post the answer ? with example ? i tried many things . . :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need a dictionary, not an array of dictionaries. Using Swift, you can use `Dictionary` instead of `NSDictionary` (`Dictionary<String, Any>` or `[String: Any]`):

```
let dict: [String: Any] = [
    "name": singleItem.name,
    "planned_revenue": singleItem.planned_revenue,
    "phone": singleItem.phone,
    "description": singleItem.description,
    "email_from": singleItem.email_from,
    "probability": singleItem.probability
]

// If you need a NSDictionary, you can cast it
let nsDict = dict as NSDictionary
```

Take a look at [*Collection Types* in the Swift guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html) and the [`Dictionary` class reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/dictionary) for more information.

Comment: Thanks you so much. @redent84 :)